# How to create html select option menu with data from MySql database with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-select

How can I add values to options on select menu from MySql db with nodeJS. Instead to hard-codded below.

```
<select id="select_id" multiple="multiple">
            <label for="one">
              <option value="test">test</option>
            </label>
            <label for="two">
              <option value="test2">test2</option>
            </label>
```

I tried the code below but something not work.
It won't update the select menu but on `console.log(select)` give it me the select menu that I whant, but not in the html view

```
fetch('/data').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{

        var select = document.getElementById("chkveg");
        console.log(select);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
                txt = document.createTextNode(data[i].username);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",data[i].username);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
    })
```

with code below works fine. Two code blocks give it me same result on `console.log(select)`

```
var select = document.getElementById("chkveg"),
      arr = ["html","css","java"];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
        txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
    select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
```

Comment: Would tell your options are strange - there should be properties of option like value & text - createTextNode is useless or even wrong, there may be also some problems with current selection or existing items.

Comment: Maybe, but the last code block works fine. Why the code above the last won't...

Comment: 2 answers here showing similar code: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23611232 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23611107 Code looks same, maybe your data are different - try to log and show JSON.strigify(data)

Answer (score 0):

fetch('/data').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{

```
    var select = document.getElementById("chkveg");
    console.log(select);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option"),
        option.text = data[i].username;
        option.value = data[i].username;
        select.add(option, select.length-1);
    }
})
```